# Django usercreation form not creating user after authentication

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am currently learning Django and working on a project to help me learn, I created my custom usercreation form and everything seems to work except when i fill in the form it does not create a new user, when i open the sign up page it seems to see it as a request to create a new user and doesnt create one since the form hast been filled and it isnt valid and even when i do fill it still doesnt seem to think its valid and renders the sign up form again.

i put two print statements in the sign up function in views.py one in the if statement and one outside just to know if a user was actually created from the console and every single time it says user not created meaning the form is never valid

views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print("User is valid")
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if new_user is not None:
                authlogin(request, new_user)
                redirect('home/')
                print("User created")
    form = RegisterForm()
    print("User not created")
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id':'RegisterUsername',
            'type':"text",
            'required':'',
            'maxlength':'16',
            'minlength':'4   ',
        })
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id':'RegisterEmail',
            'type':"email",
            'required':'',
        })
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id':'RegisterPassword',
            'type':"password",
            'required':'',
        })
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({
            'id':'RegisterPassword2',
            'type':"password",
            'required':'',
        })
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

signup.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-box login">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form method='POST' id='signup-form' novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class='icon'><ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon></span>
                    {{form.username}}
                    <label>Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class='icon'><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon></span>
                    {{form.email}}
                    <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class='icon'><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
                    {{form.password1}}
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <span class='icon'><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
                    {{form.password2}}
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                </div>
                <button type='submit' class='btn'>Register</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Why did you put a `novalidate` attribute in your `<form>` tag?

Comment: i was just trying different things i thought i had sent the updated code where i had removed it

Comment: You don't have to provide all the fields in your `.update()` call. Also, I think some of your overwrites of widget attributes are useless and prone to errors. Exemple : Are you sure that the id of the `password1` widget is `RegisterPassword` and not `RegisterPassword1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put below form,

`if request.method == 'POST': form = RegisterForm(request.POST)`

and when you add new user you should send request parameter as the first parameter

`new_user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)`

Comment: i did this and it still has the same issue

Comment: Ok last thing, can u put form.save before username and password assigments.                ` form.save()  username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')`